# Error on scroll function IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem on scroll function in IE.

Here the code http://jsfiddle.net/VdNQL/

Here the problem is, when you click the link(top) its will go the particular place, but before it just shack one time after it goes. It nice to view in Firefox and chrome. I think the problem is jquery. Here my jquery.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){            
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('div').addClass("k");
            } else {
                $('div').removeClass("k");
            }
        }); 

   $("a").bind('click', function() {
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(hash).position().top - 50 }, 1000);
  });

  });
```

Thanks for you advice.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "but before it just shack one time after it goes", as it makes no sense to me

Comment: when you click on the link the page is dancing and then animation function is become active to move on corresponding id. please visit the link in ie. you can understand what I like to told.

Answer (score 4):

Just stop the default action of the link element with `.preventDefault()`

```
$("a").bind('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(hash).position().top - 50 }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VdNQL/2/

Comment: Yeah thank you. its work. Can you tell me why we give  `ev.preventDefault();` in my code. what is this function and why we want to use here. actually what its doing here?

Comment: When clicking on a link such as `<a href="#one">Scroll</a>` the default browser behaviour would be to jump to the referenced anchor/id `one`. That's what IE is doing here before the animation actually starts. With `.preventDefault()` we just stop this happening.

Comment: A bit more info on how `preventDefault` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

That is because your href click is also trying to work at the same time. Prevent the default a href behavior. This remvoed the jerk/shaking behavior.

```
$("a").bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(hash).position().top - 50 }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Yeah thank you. its work. Can you tell me why we give  `ev.preventDefault();` in my code. what is this function and why we want to use here.

Comment: @Selva it basically says not to execute the default action for the event. Check this jQuery Api for more details [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are adding the class **k** to the div when the windows scrolltop is greater than 50. In class k you are setting the **top** to **1px**. So your script will set the top to 1px and then starts the animation. I hope that is the reason for shacking in IE.